# Can anyone use the JEL classification system?

Tags: thesis, economics

Can anyone use the JEL classification system, or is it only reserved for published (scientific) papers? This is the information I got on AEA's site

*''JEL Codes are used to classify articles, dissertations, books, book reviews, and **working papers***''.

I'm working on a university thesis related to finance, and I wanted to use the JEL classification system. Does this fall under the category 'working papers'?

Comment: I don't understand. What would prevent you from saying "my thesis would fall under category XYZ of the JEL classification"? Why would you need permission from anyone for that?

Comment: A thesis would surely fall under the category of dissertations.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi my gut feeling also says that it should be possible, however I thought maybe it was not common practice for master theses. I searched online and found that the JEL code is included in the guidelines of some universities. So I assume its fine to use the JEL code 
http://remi.bazillier.free.fr/ResearchMethodology2M2R_2016-2017.pdf
http://hec.unil.ch/attachments/msc/stages/internship-thesis-guidelines-mscf
https://emle.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/How-to-write-an-EMLE-thesis-2017-2018.pdf

@ astronat I thought they meant PhD dissertations with that, but not sure.

Comment: Also to get a conclusive answer, I have email AEA. If I get a reply, I will post that here. This question is on top of google, therefore the answer might help others

Comment: But why would it not possible? Who would prevent you from doing it?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I got a reply from the AEA helpdesk, see their answer below. Nothing prevents me from doing it, but just wanted to confirm it since I mainly saw it done in published papers.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use the word "can" in your title, since it seems clear that you *can* use the system - nobody can stop you, and it's not unethical or illegal in any way.  It sounds like the real question is whether it is *common* to use it for a thesis.  Perhaps you can rephrase your question to make this more clear.

Comment: It seems to me if you want to put this in a conspicuous place on your thesis, you will need to consult with your specific university's thesis style/formatting guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the AEA helpdesk. This is the answer I got:

*'Any work related to economics can be classified according to the JEL
taxonomy.   The list in that sentence is not intended to be an
exhaustive enumeration of where JEL Classifications are allowed to be used.'*

Therefore it's perfectly fine to use the JEL classification in a master thesis, as long as the work is related to economics.